# UIBarButtonItem change font after close modal ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I set default appearance in AppDelegate:

```
NSDictionary *barButtonAppearanceDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : FONT_MAIN_NAVIGATION};
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateApplication];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateReserved];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

I open first ViewController (navigation bar item is OK= FONT_MAIN_NAVIGATION) and then I open modal ViewController and when dismiss modal viewController first ViewController change navigation bar item to default. Why did it change it back to default, because I do not set it anywhere else. How could I prevent (fix) it.

Comment: what is in your ViewController's `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` functions?

Comment: I comment out everything from `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` but still  `UIBarButtonItem ` change font.
I tried one fix - create buttons again in `viewWillAppear` and it create it with correct font.